# How do I get the values I submitted on a form and pass it onto my modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in my jsp wherein I enter a value. This is then inserted into a table on my database. However, I would like to ask the user first to confirm his submission. I used this:

```
function askConfirmation() { 

    var confirmSubmission = confirm("Do you wish to add this entry?");

    if(confirmSubmission) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Although this does the task of suspending submission, it's not quite what I had in mind. I tried using a modal but I don't know how to get the values I used from my EL and place it in the modal after the button click. How do I do this?

Comment: is this a window modal or a jquery modal ?

Comment: It's a window modal. I'm using the bootstrap plugin.

Comment: The values you used in your EL will be already rendered in the client so you can get the content of the elements with javascript when for example the event show.bs.modal fires

Comment: what you are doing seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1239/ . Whats the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you have your form inputs setup, but you can pass an object representing all your form inputs as an argument into askConfirmation() function and then pass that to confirm(). This will display to the user all the information in the form. Eg.

```
function askConfirmation(formInput) { 
  var confirmSubmission = confirm(formInput);
  if(confirmSubmission) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
}
```

So in this way, you can access members/fields in the object and format them accordingly. You can also use jquery dialog() function to achieve this if you don't like the lnf of the window. The bottomline is, just pass the object that represents your inputs value into whatever that is used in displaying to the user for further confirmation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As  Felipe T mentioned your values are already rendered you just need to get them with javascript here's an example using bootstrap modal https://jsfiddle.net/tf021so9/6/

```
-
```

However, I prefer using a confirmation dialog plugin in such cases like this one :https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

```
-
```